# How to fixed the navigation content?

Tags: css

I have a problem on my webpage with the placement of search inputbox and button on navigation header. When I minimize the browser inputbox and button move's around. I just want them to be fixed and re-sized according to page size. Can anyone please help me on this issue.

Comment: and you have tried what exactly?

Comment: I tried by fixing the min-width and applied margin- auto but fails to fix @ Christopher Kenney

Comment: @fathima - could you put some code up, or give us a link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Really need to see some code but at a guess I would say that you need to add position relative to the outside container and then add position absolute to the container that is holding your search fields.